# Change text in multiple divs with same class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

I have a list of football matches and would like to replace all scores with "?-?" when pressing a button and toggle back to show the score when pressing again.

```css
div {
  display: table;
}

div div {
  display: table-row;
}

div div div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.score {
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide scores!</button>
<br>  <br>
<div class="table">

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Manchester United</div>
    <div class="score">1-1</div>
    <div class="team2">Liverpool</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Juventus</div>
    <div class="score">2-0</div>
    <div class="team2">Inter Milan</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Real Madrid</div>
    <div class="score">1-4</div>
    <div class="team2">Barcelona</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Dortmund</div>
    <div class="score">3-0</div>
    <div class="team2">Bayern Munich</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">PSG</div>
    <div class="score">0-1</div>
    <div class="team2">Marseille</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have experimented with getElementById and innerHTML, but due to the large number of matches I would prefer to use getElementsByClassName instead. I've seen people recommending querySelectorAll() for this, but I can't get the scripts to work.

An alternative would be to run a script replacing all numbers with a question mark inside divs with the same class.

Please help me out by using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81sLsgnc/)

Comment: Try to get all elements and the do a loop changing the values, like this:
`
var allClassses = $(".match");

for (var i = 0; i < allClassses.lenght; i++){
 allClassses[i].innerText = "the text you want";
}`

Comment: Please show us what js you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you Calvin but I'm afraid my knowledge about scripts is very limited and I'm not sure what to put where. Do you mind adding it to the existing fiddle?

Comment: @Pete I have tried different versions of onclick="document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Hello Dolly.';" combined with jQuery, but it only works for individual divs with unique Ids.

Comment: We need to see your current so it narrows down how we respond, as it stands your question is too broad as there are too many ways to do what you want (as you can see from all the different answers).  Therefore it is off topic for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your html code

```js
$.each($('.score'), function(key, score) {
  var score_text = $(score).text();
  $(score).data('score', score_text)
})

$('button').click(function() {
 if ($(this).data('hiding-score')) {
   $(this).data('hiding-score', false);
    $.each($('.score'), function () {
      $(this).text($(this).data('score'));
    });
  } else {
    $(this).data('hiding-score', true);
    $('.score').text('?-?');
  }
})
```

```css
div { display:table; }
div div { display:table-row; }
div div div  { display:table-cell; }
.score { color:blue; padding:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide scores!</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="table">

<div class="match">
<div class="team1">Manchester United</div>
<div class="score">1-1</div>
<div class="team2">Liverpool</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
<div class="team1">Juventus</div>
<div class="score">2-0</div>
<div class="team2">Inter Milan</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
<div class="team1">Real Madrid</div>
<div class="score">1-4</div>
<div class="team2">Barcelona</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
<div class="team1">Dortmund</div>
<div class="score">3-0</div>
<div class="team2">Bayern Munich</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
<div class="team1">PSG</div>
<div class="score">0-1</div>
<div class="team2">Marseille</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses `querySelector` only to select the `button` and the `.table` element to toggle a class.

The rest is all CSS, so no looping is needed.

Note that this exchanges your `.score` text content for a `data-score` attribute.

```js
document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector("div.table").classList.toggle("hide-score");
  });
```

```css
.table .score:after {
  content: attr(data-score);
}

.table.hide-score .score:after {
  content: "?-?";
}
```

```html
<button>Hide scores!</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="table">

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Manchester United</div>
    <div class="score" data-score="1-1"></div>
    <div class="team2">Liverpool</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Juventus</div>
    <div class="score" data-score="2-0"></div>
    <div class="team2">Inter Milan</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Real Madrid</div>
    <div class="score" data-score="1-4"></div>
    <div class="team2">Barcelona</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">Dortmund</div>
    <div class="score" data-score="3-0"></div>
    <div class="team2">Bayern Munich</div>
  </div>

  <div class="match">
    <div class="team1">PSG</div>
    <div class="score" data-score="0-1"></div>
    <div class="team2">Marseille</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

To support older browsers, you could instead keep the score as text content, but put it in a `span` with another `<span>?-?</span>` next to it, and then configure the CSS to hide the `:first-child` and show the rest  as needed.

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78m4de3q/)** with plain old Javascript.

But I have to admit, @SkinnyPete's way is way better and easier to understand ! You shouls use it if you're only to hide the score. This is the best way to go.

```
// Mandatory JS code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const score = document.getElementsByClassName('score')
const button = document.getElementById("hide")
const initialState = []

for(let i = 0; i < score.length; i++){
    initialState.push({initial : score[i].innerHTML})
}

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const dynamicScore = document.getElementsByClassName('score')
  for(let i = 0; i < dynamicScore.length; i++){
     if(dynamicScore[i].innerText === initialState[i].initial){
        dynamicScore[i].innerHTML = "?-?"
     }else{
        dynamicScore[i].innerHTML = initialState[i].initial
     }
  }
})
```

i added an id "hide" to your button this works fine

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would recommend is that you make use of data attributes on the divs to store the scores. i.e. `<div class="score" data-for="1" data-against="1">1-1</div>`. Then it's easier to toggle the values. Since you're using jQuery,

```
// Set the values to ?-?
$('.match .score').html('?-?');

// set the actual scores
$('.match .score').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).data('for') + '-' + $(this).data('against'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I would use the temporary storage. U can set the values for each element with the data()-Method

```
//STORE DATA IN TEMP STORAGE
$( ".score" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).data("score-temp", $(this).text());
});
```

On Click-Event I would add a class "hide-score" to distinguish between both states. And if hide-score is already set, than you reset the values from the temporary storage

```
$("button").click(function() {
   if ($(".table").hasClass( "hide-score" )) {
     $(".table").removeClass("hide-score");

     //set VALUE FROM TEMP STORAGE
     $( ".score" ).each(function( index ) {
        var score_temp = $(this).data("score-temp" );
        $(this).text(score_temp);
     });  
  }
 else {
   $( ".score" ).text("?-?");   
   $(".table").addClass("hide-score");
 }
});
```